# How to add margin between elements when alongside each other but not when stacked? [bootstrap]

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button, margins

So basically I have 2 buttons that I want to put a 20px space between. On mobile though the buttons are stacked and they are 20px off center. Anyone have any ideas? I've heard someone say use the btn-toolbar class but it didn't seem to work..

Answer (score 0):

Throw this media query at the bottom of your CSS file:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    // declare CSS rules for your target buttons
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a bit of custom CSS

```
//Mobile First Responsive View full width Stacked Buttons
.button-holder .btn{margin-right:0;width:100%;display:block;} 

@media screen and (min-width: 480px){
  //Tablet/Desktop View left aligned buttons
  .button-holder .btn{width:auto;margin-right:20px;display:inline-block;}   
}
```